# Install software without being a sudoer on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I created a new user account for a friend on my VPS. How do I let him install software for his own account that wont effect other users and not have to add him to the sudoers file?

Answer (score 4):

Tell him to download and compile the source code of the applications himself!

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
```

Comment: Sorry for the joke, but the question is not programming related.

Comment: Maybe intended as a joke, but this is a completely valid answer.